# Skip container ID and BOS descriptor query for USB device

Tags: usb, usb-device

When trying to perform `fastboot` commands, the transfer is always erroneous. [A quick search](https://community.e.foundation/t/howto-fix-fastboot-when-using-windows-10-usb-3/33982) points to certain incompatibility with USB 3.0 ports.

Forcing legacy USB 2.0 mode is not present in my BIOS settings and [not possible on OS side](https://superuser.com/questions/812022/force-a-single-usb-3-0-port-to-work-as-usb-2-0) so I would have to rely on a software solution, which looks at least feasible, as several sources offer a solution on Windows by adding the registry entries:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\18D1D00D0100" /v "osvc" /t REG_BINARY /d "0000" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\18D1D00D0100" /v "SkipContainerIdQuery" /t REG_BINARY /d "01000000" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\18D1D00D0100" /v "SkipBOSDescriptorQuery" /t REG_BINARY /d "01000000" /f
```

As such, my question would be: **What would be the equivalent solution on Linux?**

I attempted to search about BOS descriptor and container ID on Linux, but to no avail other than `libusb` sources.

Relevant `dmesg` logs:

```
[ 1467.568758] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1467.718322] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=d00d, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1467.718325] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1467.718326] usb 1-1: Product: Android
[ 1467.718327] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Google
[ 1467.718327] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 832ec5e4
////// Here I executed `fastboot devices`
[ 1476.552829] usb usb5-port1: over-current condition
[ 1476.636501] usb usb6-port1: over-current condition
[ 1484.336743] usb usb5-port1: over-current condition
[ 1484.416485] usb usb6-port1: over-current condition
[ 1487.100726] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: USB core suspending port 1-1 not in U0/U1/U2
[ 1487.100879] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1487.100987] usb 1-1: Failed to suspend device, error -32
[ 1490.074492] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: UCSI_GET_PDOS returned 0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving into the various documentation, here is how I managed to solve the problem:

```
echo -1 | sudo tee /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
echo '18d1:d00d:k' | sudo tee /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/quirks
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/pm_qos_no_power_off
echo | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup
echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/control
echo -1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
echo n | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/usb2_hardware_lpm
```

Might be a bit redundant but it works. Change the USB port as per the port being plugged in. My device is a Xiaomi Mix 2S. Change `18d1:d00d` to the hardware in question as appropriate.

Reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/driver-api/usb/power-management.html https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?highlight=usb-storage.quirks

My reasoning is that,

- The issue happens a bit non-deterministically (sometimes right after plugging in, sometimes even after a few queries to the bootloader), so is unlikely to be within `fastboot` itself. Power-related issues tend to manifest in such a way so I suspected this.
- There is no dedicated driver for the device (`lsusb -t`) so `usbcore` and the "raw" USB device is likely the point of interest.

I am still not so sure about the underlying mechanism of power management and how it correlates to the Windows solution of bypassing the two queries. According to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-usb-blog/usb-2-1-2-0-1-1-device-enumeration-changes-in-windows-8/ba-p/270775), it might be the relation between BOS descriptors and LPM capacities.

Further expansions to this answer would be greatly appreciated.